# Adjectif en tant qu'adverbe ?

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> […] s'en alla au labourage[…]  d'où il revint ayant grand appétit; car c'était la première fois qu'il travaillait aussi rude, et un peu de fatigue est un souverain remède contre le chagrin.

L'emploi qui semble normal de nos jours c'est « première fois qu'il travaillait aussi rudement ». Est-ce que l'usage de l'adjectif en tant qu'adverbe est encore permis ? En particulier, dans ce texte, est-ce qu'il s'agirait d'un emploi spécial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce n'est pas un emploi très spécial, en tout cas, il est rare mais on le retrouve chez d'autres auteurs. *Rude* est utilisé ici comme un adverbe et aucune loi n'interdit de continuer à le faire aujourd'hui.

La proximité avec ***travailler dur*** (plus courant que *travailler durement*) joue probablement un rôle dans cet usage. *Travailler rude* a d'ailleurs été choisi comme traduction de *hard work* dans *Our Mutual Friend* de Charles Dickens:

> *[...] and it is daily and nightly hard work to keep it so.*

> [...] il faut travailler nuit et jour, et travailler rude pour la maintenir telle qu'elle est.